# Extract Values from a string [Python]

Tags: python

I have two type of strings which looks like the following:

```
#Type 1:
1633659717.630234 DEBUG src/main.rs                    L662  : Binning flow x.x.x.x:xxxx->y.y.y.y:yyyy/UDP: bins (tensors) are [6, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1].
#Type 2: 
1633659717.630234 DEBUG src/main.rs                    L662  : Binning known flow moments for type "VTC": bins (tensors) are [6, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I will like to extract the array at the end of the string and the type if present. I tried doing it using `split()` function so that the string gets converted to array and I can use indexing to extract the values. But due to uneven presence of white spaces the indexing is not properly working. I also tried doing `strip()` first but the whitespaces in the array are not getting removed so the `split()` is also not working properly. I want the array to be a single element after split operation so that indexing can be utilized. Is there any efficient way of doing this? I have put the spaces so that the string looks exactly like what I see.
I am able to extract the array but what if there is type present how shall I extract both array and type from the string.

Code:

```
with open('abc.log','r') as dataFile:
    lines = dataFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.__contains__('Binning'):
           print (line.split('are ')[1])
```

Output:

```
[6, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1].
```

But this code is not efficient. I have to have two logic for extracting values. Is there a simpler and easy way?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: use the find method, it will return an index and you can then access the string at that index

Comment: this sounds like a great application for [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), and a great tool to help you craft regex search patterns is with regex101.com

Comment: "But this code is not efficient." -- why not? Seems reasonable to me. In any event, you might find `ast.literal_eval` useful for converting the string containing the list into an int list.

Comment: @JohnColeman Because if you see the Type 2 string then there is app type present like "VTC". So from the Type 2 string I have to extract the type of the app it is and the array also. So I have to have multiple logic for each cases. I want something that will extract the array and if type "VTC" etc are present it will extract that too using a single logic

Comment: are the types always in the form "SOMELETTERS"?

Comment: @diggusbickus Yes. type like "VTC" etc or app name like "Skype" always in letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re` like this:

```
import ast
import re

ast.literal_eval(re.search("\[.*?\]", my_string).group(0))
```

---

Input:

```
my_string="""
#Type 1:
1633659717.630234 DEBUG src/main.rs                    L662  : Binning flow x.x.x.x:xxxx->y.y.y.y:yyyy/UDP: bins (tensors) are [6, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1]."""
```

---

Output:

```
[6, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```